# Playwright codegen opens an incognito tab by default. Is it possible to open a regular tab instead?

Tags: playwright, playwright-python, codegen

Playwright codegen is designed to open an incognito tab by default. Is it possible to open a regular tab instead? This is particularly important as I need to install an extension while recording the tests.

```
playwright codegen
```

Answer (score 0):

no, codegen or any chromium instance launched by playwright uses incognito mode by default. It does not open in a normal browser instance. [Check the documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/codegen-intro#running-codegen)